# How to Retrieve Name | Value pair in Listview for Multiple Checked Items?

Tags: android, listview

My list view is working fine and populating all items from cursor.
i need to assign get the id of the assigned name in the list view.
I am using multiple check boxes to select items from list view.
**How can i get the Name|Value pair from listview for selected items?.**

```
   ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        try
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.servicelist_item);

        //String[] sports ;


        //get jobtype 
        Cursor cur=dbHelper.fetchByJobNumber(stringJobnumber);
        String cur_type;
        cur_type=cur.getString(18);

        //passing jobtype to fetch service items through cursor
        Cursor cursor=dbHelper.fetchItemsByType(cur_type);
        ArrayList<String> sports=new ArrayList<String>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {
           do 
           {
               //assigning cursor items to arraylist variable sports
              /* assigning item name to list view*/
              /*My cursor holds name value pair */
               sports.add(cursor.getString(3)); 
           } 
           while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }



        //setting array adapter to populate listView
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, sports);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

   }
```

//Onclick method

```
 public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) 
        {
            // Item position in adapter
            int position = checked.keyAt(i);
            // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
            if (checked.valueAt(i))
                selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));
        }

        final String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];
        Log.e("selectedItems.size()====>>", ""+selectedItems.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) 
        {
            Log.e("selectedItems====>>", ""+selectedItems.get(i));
            outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I would create an object that holds your name and id:

```
public class Sport {
     private String id;
     private String name;
     public Sport(String id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
     }

     public String getId(){
         return id;
     }

     public String getName(){
         return name;
      }
}
```

I have often needed this feature, so what I did was create a custom adapter that has a `String[]` of ids, and `List<T>` for your data, and a map `<String, T>`. Doing this gives your list a few nice features like accessing by id and position. Where this adapter will maintain 3 instances of data, I recommend only using it for lists that are relatively smaller (less than 100).

Here is the adapter I like to use:

```
public abstract class MappedAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    private Map<String, T> mMap;
    private ArrayList<String> mIdList;

    public MappedAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<T> arrayList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mMap = new HashMap<>();
        mIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T object : arrayList) {
            add(object);
        }
    }

    public MappedAdapter(Context context, T[] arrayList){
        this.mContext = context;
        mMap = new HashMap<>();
        mIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T object : arrayList) {
            add(object);
        }
    }

    public abstract String getObjectId(T object);

    public abstract String getObjectString(T object);

    public T getObject(int position) {
        return mMap.get(mIdList.get(position));
    }

    public String getObjectId(int position){
        return mIdList.get(position);
    }

    public boolean add(T object) {
        final String id = getObjectId(object);
        if(!mMap.containsKey(id)){
            mIdList.add(id);
            mMap.put(id, object);
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void remove(T object){
        final String id = getObjectId(object);
        mIdList.remove(id);
        mMap.remove(id);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Map.Entry<String, T> getEntry(int position){
         HashMap<String, T> entry = new HashMap<>();
         String key = mIdList.get(position);
         entry.put(key, mMap.get(key));
         return (Map.Entry<String, T>) entry;
     }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mMap.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mMap.get(mIdList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        T object = mMap.get(mIdList.get(position));
        if (view == null) {
            int layoutResource = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(layoutResource, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tv.setText(getObjectString(object));
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is an adapter class I use a lot that you just pass in a list, and you can access it by id and position. And will not allow for duplicate objects. It takes a generic so you can use this for many different objects.

This will ask you to override two methods:

1. `getObjectId()` Object id is what it will use as the id/key to build the map.
2. `getObjectString()` The objectString is what string you want to display in the list view

By default this will be using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` for its layout. Obviously, you can change this, or better yet, build a sub class and override the `getView()`

---

**Usage:**

```
   MappedAdapter<Sport> mappedAdapter = new MappedAdapter<Sport>(context, sports){
        @Override
        public String getObjectId(Sport object) {
            return object.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public String getObjectString(Sport object) {
            return object.getName();
        }
    };

    ListView listView =  ... ;
    listView.setAdapter(mappedAdapter);
```

To get your Key|Value pair, you can get it by position :

```
   Map.Entry<String, Sport> entry = mappedAdapter.getEntry(positon);
   String key = entry.getKey();
   Sport sport = entry.getValue();
```

Let me know if you need any clarification. Happy to help.